# texteditor scroll hidden in swiftUI

Tags: swiftui, text-editor

I want to hidden scroll indicator in textEditor.
Support from swiftui modifier, uikit possible ways in?

```
TextEditor(text: $context)
                        .foregroundColor(self.context == contextPlaceholder ? Color.grayA7 : Color.gray23)
                        .font(.bodyRegular)
                        .focused($isTextFieldsFocused)
                        .background(Color.grayF5)
                        .lineSpacing()
                        .padding(.vertical, 23)
                        .padding(.horizontal, 20)
                        .textSelection(.disabled)
                        .onTapGesture {
                            if self.context == contextPlaceholder{
                                self.context = ""
                            }
                        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [`Introspect`](https://github.com/siteline/SwiftUI-Introspect):

```
TextEditor(text: $context)
    .introspectTextView { textView in
        textView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = false
    }
```

Comment: You have to add `import Introspect`

Comment: Thank you ! However, I received it through swiftpm and did it, but it doesn't work. Is there anything I need to work on after adding it with swiftpm?
https://www.notion.so/rriver2/4509811e84784653bf9d035ea9183a81

Comment: Copy & paste the code, then you should be good to go!

Comment: please check the link. ( I tried it but It's not working)

Comment: Ignore it, try to run

Answer (score -1):

if need textEditor hide scrollIndicators in iOS 16 Swift write this code:

TextEditor(text: $text)

> .scrollIndicators(.hidden)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).